# How to use multiple layouts with Nuxt Content?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I'm using Nuxt Content and love it.  I've created a _slug.vue page using a specific layout:

```
<script>
export default {
    layout: 'not-default',
    async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
        const doc = await $content(params.slug || "index").fetch();
        return { doc };
    }
};
</script>
```

However, I would like some content to be displayed with a separate layout.  Is there a way I can do this without creating pages?  I want to do it using Nuxt Content if I can.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating multiple _slug.vue files and placed them in folders.